# Removing HTML element

Tags: javascript, html

help me with my script
when I open my file on fullscreen (over 768px), I move my pointer around the logo div and nothing happened, but when I resize my browser to below 768px and resize it again to above 768px and tried to move my pointer around the logo div and the `<a>` element that I make is keep showing up.. which is not supposed to be happen

HTML

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        <a id="aLogo" href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="hide" id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Form</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var headDiv = document.getElementById('header');
var logoDiv = document.getElementById('logo');
var naviDiv = document.getElementById('navigation');
var aLogo = document.getElementById('aLogo');
var ulNav = naviDiv.childNodes[1];
var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");
/*create <a> tag starts*/
      var aHome = document.createElement('a');
      aHome.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Home"));
      aHome.setAttribute("href","#header");
      var newLi = document.createElement('li');
      newLi.appendChild(aHome);
/*ends*/      
function showobj (e){//show object and add <a> tag to HTMl
    naviDiv.classList.remove('hide');
    naviDiv.classList.add('show');
    ulNav.insertBefore(newLi,ulNav.childNodes[1]);
}
function hideobj (e){//hide object and remove <a> tag from HTML
    ulNav.removeChild(ulNav.childNodes[1]);
    naviDiv.classList.remove('show');
    naviDiv.classList.add('hide');
}
function mediaQuery(x) {//Minimize navbar if screen under 768px
  "use strict";
    if (x.matches) {
      logoDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", showobj);
      naviDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", hideobj);
      aLogo.addEventListener("click", function(e){e.preventDefault();});//removes "a" fucntion
  }
}
mediaQuery(x);
x.addListener(mediaQuery);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vwbo9exg/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `aHome` element you can give it an id.

```
aHome.setAttribute("id","homeA");
```

Then you hide it if the screen size is over 769px

```
@media (min-width:769px) { /*if screen over 768px*/
    #homeA {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

This should answer your question. But you have another pretty fatal bug. When you resize the screen to over 769px you have to remove the listeners on your elements

```
function mediaQuery(x) {//Minimize navbar if screen under 768px
    "use strict";
    if (x.matches) {
        logoDiv.addEventListener("mouseover", showobj);
        naviDiv.addEventListener("mouseleave", hideobj);
        aLogo.addEventListener("click", function(e){e.preventDefault();});//removes "a" fucntion
    }else{
        logoDiv.removeEventListener("mouseover", showobj);
        naviDiv.removeEventListener("mouseleave", hideobj);
        aLogo.removeEventListener("click", function(e){e.preventDefault();});
    }
}
```

If you don't, the list items are removed one at a time whenever you hover over the `naviDiv`

I hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much @Kokogino it really helps